# What's the difference between opening spark-shell on cmd versus on "opening cmd as adminstrator"?

Tags: python, java, scala, apache-spark, cmd

I tried the following basic scala command (for apache spark) on cmd normally and got an error: -

```
val no = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
no.collect()
```

ERRROR:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abhay.saini\.scala_history (Access is denied)

ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: C:\Users\abhay.saini\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-c774e989-eccc-4f2a-92f7-018f2cafa507\repl-8e3a8237-a9fc-4101-99fc-153e4f584f1a
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Users\abhay.saini\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-c774e989-eccc-4f2a-92f7-018f2cafa507\repl-8e3a8237-a9fc-4101-99fc-153e4f584f1a\$line15\$read.class
```

and it immediately comes out of the spark environment.

However, while running the same thing on cmd (as administrator) it gives the correct output.

What's the deal here ? Is it because of the environment variables ? (my user variables (python/spark/java home) are different from system variables) because "running as admin" means using system variables as opposed to user variables?

Comment: I think you need to first of all specify what exactly you mean when you say "as administrator". Usually this means running as yourself, but with an administrative token, not running as the user named administrator. Unless you can provide all of the information we need to be able to reproduce your specific problem, we cannot assist you to fix it. Please use the [edit] facility to make the required improvements to your question, so that we are better furnished to assist you.

Comment: right clicking cmd and running as adminstrator

Comment: As I said then, when you do that, you do not become a different user. If something is not working for you without the privilege token, then it means that you do not have the required permissions to do it. `Access is denied` seems a fairly clear indication of that.